# I just moved from Denmark to the UK. How can I change my Music Store in Ubuntu to, so that I can get a wider choice in music to buy?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

I have recently moved from Denmark to the United Kingdom. How can I change from the non-specific Europe shop (that has less music available) to the UK shop (that has more labels signed up)?

Answer (score 1):

The store is based on IP address of your client. If you are visiting from a UK IP address, you would see the UK store.

The only thing that may prevent that, is possibly if there is a session cookie or such, cached in your browser. You can log out of the Ubuntu One web site, clear the cookies and cache for the site, and then go back to https://one.ubuntu.com/music-store and log in, and it should be the UK store.